# Python encrypt email address

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption

I need to encrypt some email address and after I need to put them in a databases.

The database column is a varchar(60).

I try to use something like this:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

msg_text = 'mypersonalmail@gmail.com'.rjust(32)
secret_key = '1234567890123456' # create new & store somewhere safe

cipher = AES.new(secret_key,AES.MODE_ECB) # never use ECB in strong systems 
obviously
encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(msg_text))

print encoded.strip()
```

But if the msg_text is so long I received this error: ValueError: **Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length** 
and if the msg_text is so long and a multiple of 16 i exceed  the 60 characters

Comment: And? Figure out how long it needs to be, and make the column wider.

Comment: You could perhaps pad the input with spaces to obtain a multiple of 16. When decrypting, just trim the result.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the column width

Comment: In that case you have to limit your `msg_text` to 3x16 = 48 characters

Comment: The result with 128bit encryption, "ZkX13mku0XqecPV6b9//DbtkNRckmO1HhwrTbhvF0Cg=" should fit in your column? See https://aesencryption.net/

Comment: FYI there is absolutely no difference in how VARCHAR(60) and VARCHAR(255) is stored.  Both are a byte to say how many characters followed by that many characters.  So unless there is an external reason for it, I'd recommend changing the database rather than struggling with self-inflicted problems.

Comment: That said, something like https://github.com/antirez/smaz *might* be able to reduce how many email adddresses go over your fixed length.